# What's the difference between Thread.setPriority() and android.os.Process.setThreadPriority()

Tags: android

If I have code like:

```
Runnable r = ...;

Thread  thread = new Thread(r);
thread.setPriority((Thread.MAX_PRIORITY + Thread.NORM_PRIORITY) / 2);
```

or ...

```
    Runnable r = ...
    Thread thread = new Thread( new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);
         r.run();
       }
    });
```

**IS** the android.os.Process way required/preferred?

**WHY** is the android.os.Process way preferred/required if it is?

This is not clearly documented as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The current Dalvik implementation seems to map Java Threads one by one to the underlying linux system PTHREADs like you say. All Threads of all apps belong to the same thread group on the system, so every Thread competes with all Threads of all apps.

So currently `Thread.setPriority` should actually do the same thing as `Process.setThreadPriority`, using the smaller Java priority scale. The mapping of priorities is defined in `kNiceValues` at [vm/Thread.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/gingerbread-release/vm/Thread.c)

Comment: So it seems that process.setthreadpriority is preferred as there is a public defined group of priorities that dalvik uses whereas with thread.priority its a mapping that isn't public. Cool.

Comment: I just thought they both end up to the same OS api calls, so the only difference is the scale of the priority value. That means that even `Thread.setPriority` sets a value competing with all app's Threads. So the decision for either method is merely a question of future safety, maybe if apps threads get grouped one time...

Comment: Hey Dronus, Yeah they do both call the correct pthread call. However, using Thread.setPriority() you are using a scale of 0-10 and on Process.setThreadPriority() you are using the nice scale (+/- 20). So Yes, nice is more granular but Thread.MIN_PRIORITY, NORMAL and MAX PRIORITY are not as informative and are somewhat arbitrary when the OS lib provided declares sets of priorities deemed expected and sane. Who knows what the mapping between the 10 point scale will be down the road. Nothing says it to be linear.

Comment: The mapping is defined by `kNiceValues` as stated above. The table is not linear, however linearity doesn't mean anything as it depends on the scheduler what the meaning of the values is, and usually only the order comes into account, eg. a process is allways prefered with lower nice value as another independently how low it is. So the real effect is relative to all nice values used in the system and thus depending on the OS makers and all other app coders policies. The android values have some named C constants suffixed like `_NORMAL` or `_URGENT_DISPLAY`, pretending some meaning...

Comment: I understand how to use nice and how the priorities work. I am just stating that the order and scale that is defined in Process.setThreadPriority is probably more sane than the arbitrary mapping on java.util.Thread inside of harmony because it is in fact what is being used to define priority groups for the rest of the system. Anyways it's a moot point.

Answer (score 8):

Google uses

```
Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
```

in Volley's [Network Dispatcher](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/0e406003b5d434d8f16d7d6ad97d446060b788e6/src/com/android/volley/NetworkDispatcher.java) thread, so I would believe that using Process.setThreadPriority() is the way to go.

Comment: downvoted because "google uses it" is not a good answer sorry.
implementation accounting answers preferred..

Comment: Do you know who writes all of Google's code? A bunch of wizards and witches that only know how to write _perfect_ code.

Comment: Upvoted because this is actually a *great* answer. For those who don’t know, the Volley library had always been a Google product, officially released by “The Android Open Source Project”, documented on “developer.android.com”, and until 2012 even in the Android repository under “frameworks/support”. Though that specific API usage was introduced in a non-related commit without specific description or explanation (during repository transition): https://github.com/google/volley/commit/6772bce3d3322ccbcf6481545ffe895d5d401b39#diff-9c5b857672d17049cfa43a465bbe3a2e80383d5d346e7fb0bf3cc89d2b1cf162

Answer (score 3):

I would rely on `thread.setPriority()`. The `android.os.Process.setThreadPriority` names a real thread priority of the underliying linux OS. However, those could, but doesn't need to map to Dalvik / Java VM threads, as the VM could do threading on its own means or use system threads or a combination of both. Raising the system priority would more likely result in prioritizing your application in favor of others, if not restricted by android security constraints, but not guarantee prioritizing your current Java Thread in favor of other Java Threads in your application.

Comment: I don't know about that. Even on a modern unix machine, the java vm would make use of the native thread model. I have looked at the implementation of Process.setThreadPriority a little and yes it does set the native thread priority directly in linux. However it just seems like it's almost a more granual approach since Thread.MAX_PRIORITY - Thread.MIN_PRIORITY is only distance ~10. To create a thread model that gets interleaved within the OS's seems like it would be rather cumbersome and provide little benefit on an embedded device. I have to think there is more to it then what you suggest.