# Downloading multiple files simultaneously in Android applications

Tags: android, download

I'm writing an application for Android which let users browse a list of files and download them.
For every download, I created a thread and I download the file with an HttpURLConnection instance (by reading from the connection in a while loop).

This method works fine with one active download. But when user starts more than one, download performance degrades dramatically. Most of the time, these parallel downloads consume all the bandwidth and the users is unable to browse files (which uses another HttpUrlConnection to load the files list).

Any suggestions on refining the download system?
Thanks.

P.S.: The method that popular browsers such as Google Chrome and Firefox do seems good. Anyone knows how they work?

Comment: You could try giving the download threads a lower priority.

Comment: Doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority(int)

Example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198518/whats-the-difference-between-thread-setpriority-and-android-os-process-setthrea

Comment: Please use AsyncTask's doInBackground for getting the file with HTTP connect instead of using Thread. i m damn sure it will improve the performance

Comment: Why? AsyncTask just uses a thread pool (up to 10 threads). That's all. Creating an own Thread will not slow down your app significantly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alas, i don't know of a way to throttle certain connections. However, a practical approach would be to implement a queue of downloads to control the number of simultaneous downloads. In your case, you would probably want to only let 1 thing download at a time. This can be implemented a few different ways.

Here's a way to do it with Handlers and a Looper: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/

Edit 1:
See mice's comment. It may be smarter to have a max of 2 threads downloading at a time.

Comment: I would not recommend downloading just one stream at a time.  Problem may happen if one stream is inaccessible, downloads slow, or has other problem. Then all downloads must wait for this one to finish or error.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out the `DownloadManager` class in the android SDK.. Its only available above or  equal api level 2.3 though.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Some tutorials you might want to see..

http://jaxenter.com/downloading-files-in-android.1-35572.html

http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/