# Download manager mutiple files one at a time

Tags: android, http, download-manager

I am attempting to use the download manager and sent multiple files at a time.  since they are all coming from the same server (home server) it is causing some pretty substantial latency.  What is the easiest way (if there is one) to send only a single file to the Download manager and when it is completed then start the second?

Is there a concept of a queue?

Thank you very much,
Craig

Comment: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564664/downloading-multiple-files-simultaneously-in-android-applications) may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but this seemed to be a network issue.  My server was really bottlenecking.  I restarted the services and increased Tomcat's memory.  Once I did that then the issue went away.  Additionally the download manager was only calling a couple files at a given time.

Appears to be a network issue and has been solved.