# In Android app setting current Thread priority to less than 1 causes a force close

Tags: android, forceclose, thread-priority

I am trying to increase the priority of a thread in my application by putting:

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(N);
```

The normal priority of current thread is 5, I can change `N` to as low as 1, but if I put it to 0 or -1 I get a force close message on my phone.

Is there a reason I cannot increase the priority of this thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29) for `Thread.setPriority()`, it says the priority must be in a range defined by [`MAX_PRIORITY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#MAX_PRIORITY) (10) and [`MIN_PRIORITY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#MIN_PRIORITY) (1). Since 0 and -1 are outside that range you should be seeing an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Is this different than what is explained here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html which has thread priorities as low as -19?

Comment: Also I am confused MAX_PRIORITY gives the highest priority to a thread or MIN_PRIORITY?

Comment: Yes, it's different. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198518/whats-the-difference-between-thread-setpriority-and-android-os-process-setthre) explains it better than I can here. I'm not positive, but I believe a higher number indicates a higher priority thread.